# Substitution of texts through regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the follow dataframe of pandas:

```
           datetime                   code                                                                      
2016-12-16 07:30:00  "3080 3130 3070"
2016-12-16 08:00:00  "3020 3080 3060 3130"
```

and I would like to get:

```
           datetime           code   
2016-12-16 07:30:00  "08 13 07"
2016-12-16 08:00:00  "02 08 06 13"
```

I would like to solve through regular expressions because I am learning it.

```
test = "3080 3130 3070"
import re
pattern = re.compile('\d{4}')
...
```

any advice on how to make that change in the strings? I do not know how to continue,

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [89]: df
Out[89]:
              datetime                 code
0  2016-12-16 07:30:00       3080 3130 3070
1  2016-12-16 08:00:00  3020 3080 3060 3130

In [90]: df.code = \
             df.code.str.extractall(r'\d(\d{2})\d') \
               .unstack() \
               .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)

In [91]: df
Out[91]:
              datetime         code
0  2016-12-16 07:30:00     08 13 07
1  2016-12-16 08:00:00  02 08 06 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression to find everything between the `"`

```
(?<=\s\")([^\"]+?)(?=\")
```

*[Example on regexr101](https://regex101.com/r/nL1tLG/2)*

---

Then, you can search for the following regular expression to only use the two numbers inside the 4 numbers:

```
(?<=\d)(\d{2})(?=\d)
```

*[Example on regexr101](https://regex101.com/r/nL1tLG/3)*